# Displaying Textbox and Labels when ComboBox item is selected?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox

I'm trying to display textboxes and labels when the user has selected a particular item in the ComboBox. Here's what I have so far:

```
        If cmbApproveBody.Value = "Board" Then
        lblSignonBonus.Visible = True
        tbSignonBonus.Visible = True
        lblHardshipBonus.Visible = True
        tbHardshipBonus.Visible = True
    End If
```

However, this does not work for me. I've also tried:

```
    lblSignonBonus.Visible = (cmbApproveBody.SelectedIndex = 1)
```

But also does not work. I've placed these codes in my Page_Load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    lblSignonBonus.Visible = False
    tbSignonBonus.Visible = False
    lblHardshipBonus.Visible = False
    tbHardshipBonus.Visible = False

    If cmbApproveBody.Value = "Board" Then
        lblSignonBonus.Visible = True
        tbSignonBonus.Visible = True
        lblHardshipBonus.Visible = True
        tbHardshipBonus.Visible = True
    End If

    lblSignonBonus.Visible = (cmbApproveBody.SelectedIndex = 1)

    BindGridView()

End Sub
```

EDIT:
Here's what I have under my aspx:
`
                        
                            Approvals

```
                        <hr />

                        <div class="card pmd-card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <!-- Basic Information -->
                                <div class="details-tab">
                                    <div class="row view-basic-card" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                                            <label class="pmd-list-subtitle">Applicant ID</label>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbApproveID" class="form-control" runat="server" Style="margin-right: 15px; width: 185px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                                            <label class="pmd-list-subtitle">Applicant Name</label>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbApproveName" class="form-control" runat="server" Style="margin-right: 15px; width: 185px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <hr />

                                <!-- Contact Information -->
                                <div class="details-tab">
                                    <!-- View Card -->

                                    <div class="row view-contact-card" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                                            <label class="pmd-list-subtitle">Approving Body</label>
                                            <select id="cmbApproveBody" class="form-control" runat="server">
                                                <option>Credentials</option>
                                                <option>Med Exec</option>
                                                <option>Board</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                                            <label class="pmd-list-subtitle">Decision</label>
                                            <select id="Select1" class="form-control" runat="server">
                                                <option id="Approved">Approve</option>
                                                <option id="Deny">Deny</option>
                                            </select>                                                
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                                            <label class="pmd-list-subtitle">Decision Date</label>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbApprovalDate" class="form-control" TextMode="Date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row view-contact-card" style="margin-bottom: 10px">

                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                            <label class="pmd-list-subtitle">Comment</label>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbComment" class="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                                            <label runat="server" id="lblSignonBonus" class="pmd-list-subtitle">Sign On Bonus</label>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbSignonBonus" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                                            <label runat="server" id="lblHardshipBonus" class="pmd-list-subtitle">Hardship Bonus</label>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbHardshipBonus" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row view-contact-card" style="margin-bottom: 10px">

                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnAddApprove" class="d-none d-sm-block btn btn-sm btn-success shadow-sm"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-sm text-white-50" style="padding-right:10px"></i>Approve</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnDelApprove" class="d-none d-sm-block btn btn-sm btn-danger shadow-sm"><i class="fas fa-times fa-sm text-white-50" style="padding-right:10px"></i>Remove</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-row" style="justify-content: center; padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-lg btn-success shadow-sm modalButton" Style="margin-right: 15px"><i class="fas fa-backward fa-sm text-white-50"></i>Back</asp:LinkButton>
                                    <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="btnEditCancel" runat="server" href="#" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-lg btn-danger shadow-sm modalButton"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle fa-sm text-white-50"></i>Cancel</asp:LinkButton>--%>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <a class="closeBtn">CLOSE X</a>
                </section>`
```

Comment: The ComboBox class doesn't have a `Value` property. You can use its  `SelectedValue` property, if the `ComboBox.DataSource` has a `ValueMember`. Since you need user interaction, use the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event handler to read the current `SelectedItem` text (e..g, `cmbApproveBody.GetItemText(cmbApproveBody.SelectedItem)`). The `SelectionChangeCommitted` event is only raised when an Item is *manually* selected. Otherwise, use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: You might start by understanding what it is you're using. Is this ASP.NET Web Forms?  The `Page_Load` suggests that it is, in which case there is no `ComboBox` control, unless you're using a custom control.  There is a `DropDownList` control, but it has no `Value` property.  Regardless, the user hasn't had a chance to do anything in the page when that `Load` event is raised so if you're expecting to react to user entry then that's not happening in that code. Spend some time reading about the technology you're using and how it works.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am using VB.net

Comment: @Brian.Scalabrine What kind of application? Is it WinForms? ASP.net web application? WPF? or something else. When you first started your application you had to pick a template. What did you pick?

Comment: Greetings @Mary, to answer your question: ASP.net web application

Comment: *"I am using VB.net"*. That merely reinforces my statement that you need to understand what you're using. VB.NET and ASP.NET are not alternatives.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you. Will look into this more. I am fairly new but slowly learning.

Answer (score 0):

SO why are you coding it on `page_load`. Instead I will suggest you to code it in the `combobox_SelectedIndexChanged` event.

```
  Protected Sub cmbApproveBody_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboDimensionGroup.SelectedIndexChanged
        lblSignonBonus.Visible = True
        tbSignonBonus.Visible = True
        lblHardshipBonus.Visible = True
        tbHardshipBonus.Visible = True
  End sub
```

This will work only if you need to set those components to be visible on any selected index of the combobox.

but

if you want to set these items to be visible on certain specific values then put your `if-else` code in this code.